# Date Field last 24H and ORDER BY Other Table

Tags: mysql

I have a small problem, want to find records with a datefield in the last 24 hours, which also works great:

```
SELECT * FROM `release` WHERE (date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Now I want to sort the records after a column from another table, also works:

```
SELECT * FROM `release` AS r JOIN hits as h ON h.id = r.id ORDER BY h.hits DESC LIMIT 0,8
```

Now to my problem, I get it not to both to cobble, here my attempt (am still very new with Mysql):

```
SELECT * FROM `release` WHERE (date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS r JOIN hits as h ON h.id = r.id ORDER BY h.hits DESC LIMIT 0,8
```

But that does not work, why would be nice if someone could explain it to me.

Thank you in advance already times.

Comment: " I get it not to both to cobble"?

Answer (score 0):

Your query have join in wrong place .. for your needs you could  use a From with the select result

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( select * from `release`
  WHERE (date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  DESC LIMIT 0,8  )  r 
JOIN hits as h ON h.id = r.id 
ORDER BY h.hits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join and add the where clause after that.

`SELECT * FROM`release`r JOIN hits as h ON h.id = r.id  WHERE (r.date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY h.hits DESC LIMIT 0,8`